# Certain code in Java in Netbeans freezes Gnome in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, freeze

If I run any process, be it a shell script through Ant, or ssh which requires user-interaction. Then when started from Netbeans, this freezes my Gnome GUI. I am only able to move around the mouse but it does not respond to anything. I can still CTRL+ALT+Fx to another TTY and my PC still behaves normally (no infinite loop or so --> CPU usage is nearly 0%).

When I try to kill a process, then it says  in the `ps` listing and N/A in the System Monitor. Even with `kill -9 PID` this won't work. The only way I found to fix this is by a reboot.

I made a simple test-case, and the crash is really consistent. Always when I run this code from Netbeans (running the jar from outside Netbeans works perfectly fine), the freeze occurs:

```
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author yeti
 */
public class JavaApplication1
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // This code freezes gnome
        try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh yeti@127.0.0.1");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*To make the test-case work, you will need to run a sshd service with default settings. It will ask for password and rsa-key-fingerprint check, thus this is user-interaction. E.g. `echo "Hello world."` will not cause any problems!*

But also running a shell-script in Ant after compilation - with the `<exec>` tag - will result in the same problem.

I have no useful log-information, because around the time that the problem occurs there are no system logs. I am running Arch Linux distribution, and checked Xorg and journalct logs, but there's nothing in it that is out of the ordinary.

I have no idea how to solve this, or even where to start. I have never seen such a problem before, but my best guess is that it is a bug in Netbeans. Any help is greatly appreciated!

For example, which log-files should I really check to solve such freezes?

Comment: also see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241728